# Android - use Picasso to load a Bitmap

Tags: android, view, imageview, picasso

I'm thinking about loading a bitmap with Picasso like `Picasso.load(bitmap)` but I didn't find any api using bitmap only url/uri/path. I also check out this: https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1007

Is there anyway I can load a bitmap from RAM using Picasso?

If I just use `imageView.setImageDrawble()`, will there be any problems/concerns?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the bitmap in memory, use `setImageDrawable`. You should only make sure, when you are loading the bitmap, that it is not too big and needs resizing.

Comment: This does not answer the question